# why i can't move the player while I am trying to make space invader in c#

Tags: c#

What's wrong with my code
I am trying to make space invader by using visual studio

```
using System;

using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace _2nd_game_try
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        bool goleft, goright;
        int playerSpeed = 13;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void keydown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Left)
            {
                goleft = true;
            }
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Right)
            {
                goright = true;
            }
        }

        private void keyup(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Left)
            {
                goleft = false;
            }
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Right)
            {
                goright = false;
            }
        }
        private void gameTime_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
        private void Walk()
        {
            while (true)
            {
                if (goleft)
                {
                    player.Left -= playerSpeed;
                }
                if (goright)
                {
                    player.Left += playerSpeed;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Why do you *think* something is wrong with your code?  What specific operation isn't working as expected?  When you debug, what specific problem do you observe?  Which operation fails?  What are the values used at the time?  What is the result?  What result was expected?  Why?

Comment: You probably need to call `Walk()` from your timer_Tick.  Also it doesn't look like you have mapped any of your events to their event-handlers.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 2):

1. Enable your timer and use a valid interval.
2. Remove while (true) from `Walk()` method.
3. Call `Walk()` inside timer callbak.
4. Subscribe keyup and keydown eventhandlers.
5. Set keypreview  property  to true on your form.